# Make closeable tab

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I have this basic example of JavaFX tabs with right click menu.

```
// Right-click mouse button menu
        final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

        MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem("Close Tab");
        item2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Close Tab");
            }
        });
        contextMenu.getItems().addAll(item2);

        // Tabs
        VBox stackedTitledPanes = createStackedTitledPanes();
        ScrollPane scroll = makeScrollable(stackedTitledPanes);
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();
        // Create Tabs
        Tab tabA = new Tab();
        tabA.setText("Main Component");
        tabA.setClosable(false);
        tabA.setContextMenu(contextMenu); // Right-click mouse button menu 
        // Add something in Tab
        StackPane tabA_stack = new StackPane();
        tabA_stack.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tabA_stack.getChildren().add(new Label("Label@Tab A"));
        tabA.setContent(tabA_stack);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabA);

        Tab tabB = new Tab();
        tabB.setText("Second Component");
        tabB.setClosable(false);
        // Add something in Tab
        StackPane tabB_stack = new StackPane();
        tabB_stack.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tabB_stack.getChildren().add(new Label("Label@Tab B"));
        tabB.setContent(tabB_stack);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabB);

        Tab tabC = new Tab();
        tabC.setText("Last Component");
        tabC.setClosable(false);
        // Add something in Tab
        StackPane tabC_vBox = new StackPane();
        tabC_vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tabC_vBox.getChildren().add(new Label("Label@Tab C"));
        tabC.setContent(tabC_vBox);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabC);

        mainPane.setRight(tabPane);

        mainPane.setPrefSize(300, 500);
        mainPane.setLayoutY(32);

        scroll.setPrefSize(395, 580);
```

I want when I right click with the mouse on the tab name to select option `close`. When I select `close` I want to remove the selected tab from the tab pane. How I must modify the code to get this functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
item2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Close Tab");
                tabPane.getTabs().remove(tabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            }
        });
```